# Keras output shape is incorrect

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, classification

I'm setting up a recurrent neural network to classify words between English or French and I'm getting an error about the output shape being incorrect.

My network looks like this:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
cu_dnnlstm_1 (CuDNNLSTM)     (None, 45, 128)           79872     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 45, 128)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
cu_dnnlstm_2 (CuDNNLSTM)     (None, 128)               132096    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 258       
=================================================================

Total params: 212,226
Trainable params: 212,226
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Here is my error:
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (2,)

Here is my code:

```python
import pickle
import tensorflow as tf
import keras

from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
config.log_device_placement = 0

sess = tf.Session(config=config)
set_session(sess)

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM, CuDNNLSTM

import numpy as np

maxlen = 45
learning_rate = 0.002
characters = 26
empty = [0 for _ in range(characters)]
model_name = "language_predictor"
batch_size = 64
n_epoch = 3

with open("data_x.pickle", "rb") as file:
    x = pickle.load(file)

with open("data_y.pickle", "rb") as file:
    y = pickle.load(file)

for sequence in x:
    while len(sequence) < maxlen:
        sequence.append(empty)

x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)

model = Sequential()

model.add(CuDNNLSTM(128, input_shape=(maxlen, characters), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(CuDNNLSTM(128))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

# Compile model
model.compile(
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.002),
    metrics=['accuracy'],
)

model.summary()

model.fit(x,
          y,
          epochs=n_epoch,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          validation_split=0.1)
```

My inputs look like this: `[ [ [one hot array of letter], [more], [more] ], [another word] ]`

My outputs look like this: `[ [0, 1 one hot array of language], [1, 0] ]`

Whenever I run the program, I just get this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target:
expected dense_1 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (2,)
```

Even though, it should work because the output layer has 2 neurons.

EDIT:
Changing the loss function from "sparse_categorical_crossentropy" to "categorical_crossentropy" fixed the problem.

Comment: In your data you seem have two classes, French and English. If that's so, you shouldn't have 2 outputs neurons. The last Dense layer should have 1 neuron, and the loss function must be `binary_crossentropy`

Comment: For `out = np.array([[[[1,0], [0,1]]]]) ` use sparse categorical cross-entropy. For `out = np.array([[[1, 0]]])` use categorical cross-entropy. Or binary, if you've only got 0 and 1.